# FormData: change the field charset

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, form-data, iso-8859-1

According to this post [multipart/form-data, what is the default charset for fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085449/multipart-form-data-what-is-the-default-charset-for-fields) , posting a formdata, the default charset of the fields is ISO-8859-1.

When I send a FormData (with or without jquery), the FormData is parsed by the browser which constructs the request, but I couldn't force the charset by field (no way to change the way the browser parse the FormData).

However, if I don't specify this charset by field, then my server receives latin1 encoding (whereas I need UTF-8). Is there any way to force this charset, with or without js library?

For information, the charset cannot be set in the global Content-Type with FormData (if I force the content-type then it breaks the "boundary" tag so the server cannot parse the data).