# Rest-assured POST call with formParam not send Cyrillic correctly. I have "???" in the result

Tags: java, rest-assured

I using rest-assured 4.3.3

I send request with Content-type="multipart/formdata"

```
 Response response = RestAssured.given()
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8")
                .formParam("name", "Саша")
                .multiPart("document_type_1", credRequestItem.getDocuments().get(0).getType())
                .multiPart("document_file_1", new File(name))
                .when()
                .post("http://path")
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();
```

In formParam in value I used Cyrillic. In log I'm seeing:

```
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "--"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "6SnC_ZNf2wyvWpz1gPL5lBJAMXEEfzlqg3"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Disposition"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> ": "
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "form-data; name="name""
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Type"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> ": "
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "text/plain; charset=US-ASCII"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Transfer-Encoding"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> ": "
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "8bit"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "????"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "--"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "6SnC_ZNf2wyvWpz1gPL5lBJAMXEEfzlqg3"
13:01:16.263 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "--"
```

Cyrillic was changing on "????"
Can your help me? What I need to add in my code? (encoderConfig doesn't working). I used a lot of variants.

Comment: Try remove this line `.header("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8")`

Comment: This solution doesn't work. I'm still have "????" in log.

Comment: Your issue is more likely in that your console cannot properly show Cyrillic. Where exactly do you observe this? In IDE console or in some terminal, or in log file?

Comment: I see "????" in IDE terminal, in Elastic and in message Kafka. If I send similar request in Postman,  I see correctly Cyrillic symbols. Also I can see correctly Cyrillic symbols in IDE terminal when I use System.out.println("Саша").

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? I experience the same problem and can't find a working solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73839959/charset-of-http-response-in-java

Comment: I am not sure this is related, but the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17818574/628006) mentions that the content-type must not be sent for a `multipart/form-data` but a `_charset_` field must be set instead in the form. Your logs extract seems to confirm this as its mentioning `text/plain; charset=US-ASCII`