# Charset of http response in Java

Tags: java, http, charset

Using a standard Java HTTP Client, I load a page at this address:
**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELArlE7gSmw**

Title of this youtube video in Bulgarian. It is listed in the meta tags of the page like this:

```
<meta name="title" content="here is title">
```

I am using the following code to load this page. Pay attention to the encoding (**Windows-1251**):

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(new URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELArlE7gSmw"))
                .GET()
                .build();
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
                HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString(Charset.forName("Windows-1251")));
        System.out.println(response.body());
    }
}
```

If you look at this tag in the response (with **Windows-1251** encoding), then it will look like this:

```
<meta name="title" content="ЗАХАРОСАН�? ЧЕРВЕН�? ЯБЪЛК�?!!">
```

If you use **UTF-8** instead of Windows-1251, it will be like this:

```
<meta name="title" content="���������� ������� ������!!">
```

I have also tried other http clients, such as the client in jsoup library. The result is similar, although **[the demo version of this library](https://try.jsoup.org/)** displays all tags with Bulgarian content correctly:
[image]

How to decode http response without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

For Intellij IDEA:
File > Settings > Editor > File Encodings.

Set fields "Global Encoding" and "Project Encoding" to "System Default" (**not UTF-8 or Windows-1251, but default!**). The whole output is fixed

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you but I'm confused. The dropdown is reading windows-1251

Comment: I didn’t understand a little how it works, but my system encoding is windows-1251, and I really read utf-8 page (default body handler takes this encoding from the http header). And my console encoding is also utf-8

Comment: @g00se default BodyHandler is HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()

Comment: *but my system encoding is windows-1251* I can believe it but that is not consistent with your earlier report that your file.encoding is utf-8

Comment: Now the property "file.encoding" has become "Windows-1251", and before this change it was actually "utf-8", as I answered

Comment: Again *(not UTF-8 or Windows-1251, but default!).* (to me) tells a different story to what you're saying now. But the 'utf' output, as I said above, showed me that it was not really utf-8

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, but that's how it was. Property file.encoding was utf-8. I don’t remember what was in the dropdown list at that moment, but it was definitely not system default.

Comment: Note that in the drop-down list there are separately utf-8, windows-1251 and system default

Comment: It is interesting that I could verify the problem on my machine and fix it by just changing the code, while the @unitifilm did not change the code but the IDE setup.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple items that can (and do not have to) define the response format:

- When the client sends a request, there is a header called `Accept-Encoding`.
  This should be a hint for the server what the client wants to have.
- When the server sends the response, the server should mark up the encoding used in the header `Content-Encoding`.
- The response body may contain meta tags as you mention. The disadvantage here is that the client already needs to assume some encoding to access this data so it is less reliable.
- Still then, it seems you apply the BodyHandler for `Windows-1251` regardless of what the really used encoding is.

With that your setup looks quite fragile, and you better check if the headers Accept-Encoding and Content-Encoding are present and meaningful.

**Edit:** When testing the code from the question I was able to reproduce the reported problems. But they vanished when I simply leveraged the default behaviour of the client like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(new URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELArlE7gSmw"))
            .GET()
            .build();
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    System.out.println(response.body());
}
```

Comment: HTTP response has this header – "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8".  Using the header "Accept-Encoding: UTF-8" in my request produces the same results as I described above.

Comment: Then assume the body is UTF-8 encoded and stop using a Windows-1251 decoder.

Comment: I tried to use BodyHandler with UTF-8 encoding and header, the result is as in my description (the lines are fully broken). Header "Accept-Encoding: UTF-8" left and deleted. Both times the same result.

Comment: Strangely I do not see any title attribute in that response at all

Comment: I just used `curl` with no special headers, saved the result to file and displayed it with `less`. There are title headers, and the characters on my screen look all reasonable.

Comment: @g00se you can open try.jsoup.org, use this url and type in Selector input form expression 'meta'

Comment: OK can see it now. Def UTF-8

Comment: @hiran-chaudhuri I tried to select all the meta tags of this page using PHP and everything was also successful. It's strange that this happens in Java.

Comment: So where are you outputting these characters and how?

Comment: @unityflim Check my edited answer. I just removed this Windows-1251 decoder and it works.

Comment: @hiran-chaudhuri Tried your new example in Intellij Idea. All Cyrillic lines are broken, the console encoding is UTF-8 (the same for Windows 1251). Are you using Idea?

Comment: @g00se The usual console in the IDE, System.out.println. Console encoding is utf-8

Comment: OK so the reading as a Windows 8 bit encoding can be removed from the conversation. The encoding is utf-8

Comment: What is the value of system property `file.encoding`?

Comment: @g00se UTF-8 (Took the property with System.getProperty, right?)

Comment: Yes. Stumped. Looks like whatever is having to print that string does not think it's valid utf-8